# pjsua - getting 403 forbidden (bad auth)

Tags: python, sip, pjsip

I am using the python module for pjsua and trying to register to a PBX.

here is the code:

```
import sys
import pjsua as pj
import threading


def log_cb(level, str, len)
    print str,

class MyAccountCallback(pj.AccountCallback)
    sem = None

    def __init__(self, account)
        pj.AccountCallback.__init__(self, account)

    def wait(self)
        self.sem = threading.Semaphore(0)
        self.sem.acquire()

    def on_reg_state(self)
        if self.sem
            if self.account.info().reg_status = 200
                self.sem.release()

lib = pj.Lib()

try
    lib.init(log_cfg = pj.LogConfig(level=4, callback=log_cb))
    lib.create_transport(pj.TransportType.UDP, pj.TransportConfig(5060))
    lib.start()

    acc = lib.create_account(pj.AccountConfig("181.21.200.109:5060", "561123", "admin"))

    acc_cb = MyAccountCallback(acc)
    acc.set_callback(acc_cb)
    acc_cb.wait()

    print n
    print Registration complete, status=, acc.info().reg_status, 
          ( + acc.info().reg_reason + )
    print nPress ENTER to quit
    sys.stdin.readline()

    lib.destroy()
    lib = None

except pj.Error, e
    print Exception  + str(e)
    lib.destroy()
```

the **PBX IP is 181.21.200.109**, the **number I am trying to register is 123456**, and as for the password - I just put 123 (I don't think the PBX requires password).

I get from the PBX a sip packet SIP 403 forbidden (bad auth).

To compare, I looked at another register packet from a different sip client that registered successfully. (the PBX sends back OPTIONS Packet).

**Here are the packets:**

**This packet gets FORBIDEN (bad auth) response (failed)**

```
REGISTER sip:181.21.200.109:5060 SIP/2.0

Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 181.21.200.50:51117;rport;branch=z9hG4bKPj36c48c6ff87b47ac86c9036e0acbaed4 (Different)

Route: <sip:181.21.200.109:5060;lr> (Different)

Max-Forwards: 70

From: <sip:561123@181.21.200.109>;tag=10a3290c7748480c9c0808366ae0c840 (Different)

To: <sip:561123@181.21.200.109> (Different)

Call-ID: 94f280c9cfcf41539b500ff39582a1ef

CSeq: 21606 REGISTER

User-Agent: pjsip python

Contact: <sip:561123@181.21.200.50:51117;ob> (Different)

Expires: 300

Allow: PRACK, INVITE, ACK, BYE, CANCEL, UPDATE, INFO, SUBSCRIBE, NOTIFY, REFER, MESSAGE, OPTIONS - (Different Options)

Authorization: Digest username="561123", realm="asterisk", nonce="21f4ad6b", uri="sip:181.21.200.109:5060", response="62a339057d2b4e3fed4d368ff94f6d46", algorithm=MD5

Content-Length:  0
```

**This packet gets OPTIONS response (success)**

```
REGISTER sip:181.21.200.109:5060 SIP/2.0

Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 181.21.200.150;rport;branch=z9hG4bK4H5Z6Z2myFUNr

Max-Forwards: 70

From: <sip:561123@181.21.200.109:5060>;tag=307m6Zy8cj7pa

To: <sip:561123@181.21.200.109:5060>

Call-ID: f3ce9234-40e3-1233-a783-5c6b32d1a9b5

CSeq: 3 REGISTER

Contact: <sip:561123@181.21.200.150>

User-Agent: sofia-sip/1.12.11

Allow: REGISTER, INVITE, ACK, BYE, CANCEL, OPTIONS, MESSAGE, SUBSCRIBE, REFER, UPDATE, INFO

Supported: timer, 100rel, path

Authorization: Digest username="561123", realm="asterisk", nonce="7625cf17", algorithm=MD5, uri="sip:181.21.200.109:5060", response="dca3173b2159f812481ca0c96b10a751"

Content-Length: 0
```

**Does anybody know why am I getting the forbidden response? is there something wrong with my code?**

thanks in adcance

Answer (score 1):

Your PABX **does** require password for these accounts (otherwise we wouldn't see nonce, response and Authorization header itself) so make sure password is valid.
Asterisk may also reject registration with 403 if account is not found (configuration: alwaysauthreject=yes) and your logs don't clarify that as you've tried to register different extension from python and from standalone client.

It would be best to use same extension for comparison (but don't try registering two softphones same time to same extension).

Comment: thanks for your answer. I am out of town for a few days, when I come back I'll check it and ket you know. thanks again

Comment: okay, I tired to use the same extension this time, and also changed the password to "admin" (I don't know what the password is or how to  check it, but I think "admin" is the default). I edited the code in the question and added the packets that I received this time. I also wrote (Different) next to the fields that are different between the packets. also noticed that in the bad register packet, in the ALLOW field -  there is different actions allowed. your thoughts? thanks

Comment: Route header is added because pjsua is configured to use proxy - this is caused by proxy being set by default with python API (AccountConfig()).  It is very likely that it would break registration (it breaks registration with many commercial operators), but I don't know how to remove it, perhaps changing it inside pjsua.py, build_config() or passing empty array (see: cfg->proxy_cnt = PyList_Size((PyObject*)obj->proxy);)  would help.